# Getting ArcGIS Templates in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, installation, visual-studio

I have a work computer which has ArcGIS desktop installed first and then VS2010 (just the way IT does it) and then templates are not available, anyone know what I need to do to see the templates?

I am running this under Windows XP.

Comment: I don't get back to work until Monday so I can't check until then, but I _think_ they're not installed unless VS2010 already exists. IT may need to change their procedure (it'd probably take less time for them to do that than to try to figure out how to extract things after the fact).

Comment: Insert ArcGIS 10.0 Install DVD or CD and go to repair install option, and go find the check box for the ArcObjects templates for VS2010. It will add them on and get it added.

Comment: All you need to do is to install the SDK as @Hairy answered.  Make sure you have either a full version of VS2010 or VS2008 Express.  You cannot install the SDK with VS2010 Express alone.

Answer (score 5):

I think VS2010 only works if you point it at the .NET 3.5 framework, not the 4.0.  Kind of makes 2010 redundant imo.  I don't think it will work properly

Arc 10 (sp1) VS2010, VS 2008 and VS Express 2008 - all 3.5 Framework.
with ArcGIS 10.1 - 4.00 framework and VS2010

So:

VS2010 if you use the .net 3.5 framework. Standard and Professional work.

VS2010 Express is not supported
VS2008 Express is

ArcObjects SDK still checks for VS2008 on installation